# Postdoc, country and comfort zone

Tags: postdocs, career-path

Due to covid, I had to extend my current postdoc contract till mid of next year. My postdoc albeit with my PhD supervisor, is on different topics and in collaboration with other groups. My advisor offered me to extend it till end of the next year too.

I am starting to search for other positions in my current country of residence and also other places. But, I am starting to feel comfortable here which is killing the drive to move to new country/place.

I am single, and want to try for academia (tenure track positions) in my home country in a year. But it seems, my motivation has shifted since I graduated my PhD in February 2020. I am two mind about what I actually want to do.

How do I come out of this comfort zone and make rational choices? I am probably digging my own career grave here. I want to stay in academia but I also don't want to leave my current position this or till mid of next year. And I know that doing a postdoc with PhD supervisor is looked down upon in academia. So, I am already in a bad place career wise.

Comment: People won't hold it against you that you stay in a safe position during a pandemic. You might need an additional postdoc (after the pandemic is resolved) before starting that tenure track, though.

Comment: Comfort and safety should be very high priorities right now. But, no harm in looking around and seeing if something catches your eye.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you pursue all options open to you at the current time and delay decisions until you are required to finalize them. In other words, apply for some positions in your home country and see what develops. If they *then* seem better than your current situation, then do that. But you can also pursue options in your current country with the same goal.

Just be honest with your supervisor, who seems supportive now and may be supportive of your need to be flexible.

Many of us had to make compromise decisions along the way due to such things as a bad job market. Now it is the pandemic. People generally will understand such things and that one can't proceed now as if things were normal.